# regex - match this part only if previous part matched

Tags: java, regex

My text is of the following format :

```
<command>,<cabinet>,<drawer>,<report>
```

Rules being :

`<command>` : 3 digit letters only,
`<cabinet>` : 1-4 digit numeric,
`<drawer>`  : 1 digit alphanumeric between A to I,
`<report>` : 1-4 digit numeric

**Each segment makes sense only if the previous one exists.** 
Can assume that cabinet is always present, else, just finding the command is not useful.

Example :

```
SRH,898
SRH,898,G
SRH,898,G,900
```

Non Example :

```
SRH,,,898          // <report> without <cabinet> or <drawer>
SRH,898,,900       // <report> without <drawer>. Take only upto SRH,898  .. ignoring the rest
```

I came up with this: `[a-z$]{3},\d{1,4},([a-i])?(,\d+)?` 

**Problem:** 
 Cases like `SRH,898,,900` are valid with this regex, whereas ideally it should be invalid, as `<report>` ( 900 )  exists without `<drawer>`. I want it to try and match for the `<report>` **only if** `<drawer>` exists, in which case, the `<drawer>` will be separated by a `,` from the `<report>`, if `<report>` also exists.

I guess i can do this in two loops, the second one would filter out consecutive `,`-s , but was hoping something better can be done.

Any help ?

Thanks

**Final Update** : https://regex101.com/r/i7HnLf/3 is the good stuff :) Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Your pattern is not quite in sync with the requirements. It must be something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(?:,[0-9]{1,4}(?:,[A-Ia-i0-9](?:,[0-9]{1,4})?)?)?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess you were confused by the alphanumeric part. My bad, i modified the text a bit. command is only letters, no numerics. Thanks :)

Comment: @Somjit: just use - `^[a-zA-Z]{3}(?:,\d{1,4}(?:,[a-iA-I](?:,\d{1,4})?)?)?$`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/i7HnLf/1. Yes, the alphanumeric part. Also, you have a `$` in the first part and `+` quantifier at the end. That is what I meant by out of sync.

Comment: By using non capturing groups, the <drawer> and <report> parts are no longer captured it seems.

Comment: That is not a problem, add capturing parentheses where you need them to be, see https://regex101.com/r/i7HnLf/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That almost worked.. but these patterns can be anywhere in the middle of a line. So the ^ and $ are not applicable, and if i take those out, it matches everything

Comment: Again, think of your requirements. Maybe what you need just cannot be handled with just regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please form an answer with what you posted. It helped me find my solution. I'll accept that one.

Comment: If you managed to come up with a regex that works, you may post it yourself. I do not know how to answer this question, it is too unclear for me at this point, especially that "final" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to come up with a regex that does what you want, i.e. keep state of previously matched segments, it will be close to impossible to maintain.

Since you are going to open and parse each file, you're better off handling your requirements in your code explicitly.

Comment: I'm mining the code for 'valid' occurances. About 400 individual files, each with a 1000+ lines of assembly-ish syntax like this. Regex is my best hope, as the language by itself is legacy stuff and has no similar way of doing this.

Comment: @Somjit the fact that you have thousands of lines to read is not a good reason - the code will behave the same on one line or thousands of lines. And, if this is the issue here, a solution with regex will likely be slower and harder to read/maintain. Do it directly via code, less pain more gain.

Comment: @JChrist I think this should be a comment

Comment: With a regex you will still need to open up and parse each file, so, instead of coming up with a paranoid regex, you can handle each line with ease via code

Comment: @BackSlash My thinking was that this kind of regex usage should be avoided, thus I used an answer. But I'm not 100% sure I made the right choice of providing an answer

Comment: @JChrist Maybe you could reword it, right now it seems to be a comment, an *opinion* from a SO user, not an answer. It also contains a question, which means that you expect to receive an answer from the OP (or a *clarification*), which is what comments exist for

Answer (score 0):

The following code do the job:

```
public class FourpartsRegEx {

   static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
      "([A-za-z]{3})" + // <command> : 3 digit letters only,
      "(,"            +
      "(\\d{1,4})"    + // <cabinet> : 1-4 digit numeric,
      "(,"            +
      "([A-I])"       + // <drawer>  : 1 digit alphanumeric between A to I,
      "(,"            +
      "(\\d{1,4})"    + // <report>  : 1-4 digit numeric
      ")?)?)?" +
      ""
      );

   static void test( String expr ) {
      final Matcher m = pattern.matcher( expr );
      if( m.matches()) {
         System.err.printf( "%s match ==> %s, %s, %s, %s\n",
            expr, m.group( 1 ), m.group( 3 ), m.group( 5 ), m.group( 7 ));
      }
      else {
         System.err.printf( "%s doesn't match\n", expr );
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      // Matches
      test( "SRH,898" );
      test( "SRH,898,G" );
      test( "SRH,898,G,900" );

      // Non Matches
      test( "SRH,,,898"    ); // <report> without <cabinet> or <drawer>
      test( "SRH,898,,900" ); // <report> without <drawer>
   }
}
```

Execution:

```
SRH,898 match ==> SRH, 898, null, null
SRH,898,G match ==> SRH, 898, G, null
SRH,898,G,900 match ==> SRH, 898, G, 900
SRH,,,898 doesn't match
SRH,898,,900 doesn't match
```

Comment: Nice way to print. Although my regex problem was solved, your code helped give me some ideas :) Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2715083/somjit don't forget to accept this answer ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Check this regex:

```
^([^,][^,]*)($|,([^,][^,]*))($|,([^,][^,]*))($|,([^,][^,]*))
```

from start, search a token with at least 1 non-, 
followed by a line ending, or a , followed by another string of at least 1 non-, and so on..

tested with your examples on http://regex101.com/ and it seems to work...

EDIT: for sure, the rules of the tokens are not yet applied - think you will be able to do this yourself...

Comment: now optimized:

    ^([A-Z]{3}($|,(\d{1,4}))($|,([A-I]*))($|,(\d+))

(consider the uppercase letters when checking for uppercase letters in your input!!)

Comment: argh - missing bracket on position 10 after first token in the optimized variant:
^([A-Z]{3})($|,(\d{1,4}))($|,([A-I]*))($|,(\d+))